# tmux not executing ~/.bash_profile on start up

Tags: bash, fedora, tmux, bashrc

I searched the net and many people complained that `tmux` wasn't executing their `.bashrc`. The solution thats suggested everywhere was to source `.bashrc` from within `.bash_profile` cos `tmux` launches bash as a login shell and we can be sure that `.bash_profile` is executed for login shells.

Unfortunately, even this solution isn't working for me. I tried duplicating commands/aliases in both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`. Even that doesn't seem to work. I don't have a `.tmux.conf` file at all if that would mess up anything.

Contents of `.bash_profile` looks like

```
[pmanjunath 12:29:13 ~]$ cat .bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

Contents of `.bashrc` looks like

```
[pmanjunath 12:29:36 ~]$ cat .bashrc
PS1="\[\e[35m\][\u \t \w]$ \[\e[0m\]"
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim
PATH=$PATH:~/bins
CSCOPE_DB=~/cscope/cscope.out; export CSCOPE_DB
alias cs='`which cscope` -d'
alias fs='cd /data/fs'
alias real='cd /data/debug/src/prog/realstore'
alias mnt='cd /mnt/tintri'
alias psg='ps -eaf | grep realstore'
set -o vi
```

And launching `tmux` screws my `PS1` like below unless I rerun `~/.bash_profile`-

```
-bash-4.0$
```

**EDIT** A strange thing happened. I tried to debug tmux by hooking it up with `strace`. What I saw was, tmux was unable to find some `libevent2` library. So installed it like

```
rpm -ivh /auto/toolchain/rpms/fedora12/libevent2-2.0.21-6.tt.x86_64.rpm
```

After this, tmux started executing my bash profile BUT only when run with `strace`!! If I just say, `tmux`, the same old problem exists! I really dont know what magic is `strace` pulling off.

Comment: Can you show us the bit in `.bash_profile` where you've sourced `.bashrc`

Comment: @EightBitTony I added all additional details to the Qn. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I've tested with a new user using your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and it works perfectly fine. What happens if you add a new user with these files?

Comment: @gollum. Created a new user and copied over the contents of `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`. Still the same issue

Comment: show `strace -e open,access -f tmux`

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz Here you go. http://pastebin.com/6cLEApHA I started tmux as you suggested and then exited it with `exit`.

Comment: @PavanManjunath, this output looks strange, did you only start and stop tmux to gather it ? I mean did you run any commands within tmux window?

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz Just start and stop

Comment: Do you also have a `.profile`? If so that will be executed in preference to `.bash_profile`.